# Can I increase desktop icons larger than 128x128 on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, icon

I have a little Mac question.

Is there a way to boost the cap on desktop icon sizes from 128x128 to anything larger such as 512x512? I found some solutions for Leopard but none for Lion. It would be really cool to put my high-resolution monitor to good use :/